# Netbeans JaCoCoverage tests libraries for coverage

Tags: netbeans, libraries, jacoco

While working on a group project we had some issues with Jacoco, which we fixed by removing a duplicate Library, but now Jacoco shows coverage data for the libraries we use. How can we fix this so that the coverage data is once again clean to read?

Here is what Jacoco Shows:
[image: Here is what Jacoco Shows]

Answer (score 0):

Include in report generation only your classes and not libraries.